# Pop up come when click on button using Jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

Am using razor html .when i click a button i need divResults div need to appear in a pop up.I like to do  popup using  Jquery.pls help

```
 <div id="divResults ">
       <div class="HeadBold">
            Results
        </div>
       <div class="row MarginTop">
           <div class="col1">
              <label>
                Test
              </label>
               <label id="lblPjtEligible">
                     Test</label>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `jQuery dialog`

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

I found an example here- http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/hnm2n/

```
$(element).dialog({
    close: function() {
        if (ko.isWriteableObservable(value)) {
           value(null);   
        }
    }
});
```

Being MVC Developer I prefer bootstrap UI theme's model window.

Link- http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div id="resultsOuterDiv">
<div id="resultsInnerDiv"></div>
  </div>

<script>

  function buttonClick()
  {
   $('#resultsOuterDiv ').dialog();
   $('#resultsInnerDiv').html('Your result here');
  }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If You google it for that pop window you wwill get lot of examples , then you can customize that according to your requirement, Below are some link for Demo

[DEMO 1](http://www.alessioatzeni.com/wp-content/tutorials/jquery/login-box-modal-dialog-window/index.html)

[DEMO 2](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorials/demos/Popup_Dialog_Windows_using_JQuery.aspx)

[DEMO 3](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/650/jQuery-Custom-PopUp-Window)